# PHP cli is not running after reboot

Tags: centos, php, centos-6, autorun

To run PHP CLI on my centos virtualbox image I need to type

`source /opt/remi/php71/enable`

but after rebooting the machine the PHP CLI is down again and I need to do this again...

In best case I would like to have a PHP CLI online before HTTPD service even starts

I guess there is a way to autorun this command, but I am not sure if I would do this in the correct way

Answer (score 0):

As `enable` file is only about exporting environment paths I just did

`cp /opt/remi/php71/enable /etc/profile.d/php71.sh`

It should have a global effect on every machine user

Comment: best would be to simlink - ln -s /opt/remi/php71/enable /etc/profile.d/php71.sh

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to have a PHP CLI online before HTTPD service even starts

Apache Web server don't need this, as it use either mod_php or php-fpm, not the cli command.

Comment: Unless you work with frameworks like Laravel which comes with own tools that uses PHP CLI on boot. It should not happen, but the programmer can make it happen